# python - TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and take the first line of it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04', '01/07/2019', '01/08/2019', '01/09/2019', '01/10/2019', '01/11/2019', '01/14/2019', '24/08/2019']})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]) 

a = df['Date'].iloc[0]
```

I am trying to iterate through the df['Date'] to only include weekday's. Using a If statement with a pass give's none where it would be a weekend. I am now trying to use continue which I need a loop for. However each time I loop through it I either get TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not iterable

```
def weekday_end(day_now):

    d = day_now
    for row in d:
        if d.isoweekday()==6:
            continue
        elif d.isoweekday()==7:
            continue
        else:
            return d

for rows in a:
    df = weekday_end(rows)
    print (df)
```

Comment: It's impossible to suggest the best way because you haven't said what you're trying to do. Iterating a dataframe is something of a red flag, though.

Comment: `a` is a single `Timestamp` object, `Timestamp('2019-01-02 00:00:00')`.

Comment: You didn't take the first row of a dataframe. You took the first value of the `Date` series, a single column in the dataframe. We don't know what output you expected instead.

Comment: replace `a = df['Date'].iloc[0]` with `a = df['Date']`

Comment: @KostasCharitidis: then they'd iterate over the values in a series, not the columns in a row. Not that the OP has specified what the expected output is.

Comment: @MartijnPieters he would get all the values of his DataFrame `Date`

Comment: @KostasCharitidis: `Date` is not a dataframe. It's a series.

Comment: @KostasCharitidis: my point being that there are two possible answers here. `a = df.iloc[0]` is also an iterable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's a key in his dataframe which can be iterated

Comment: Sorry I have edit the question to include reasoning

Comment: After your edit: drop the `.iloc[0]` and use the `df['Date']` series. You picked a single value, not the column.

Comment: It'd be much more helpful if your input also included *weekend dates*; all your sample dates are weekdays. And what is the expected output of your code? What else did you want to do with the filtered timestamps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over a single value, where you wanted the whole column. That can be fixed by dropping the `.iloc[0]`:

```
a = df['Date']
```

That still won't let your code work, because your `weekday_end()` function will itself try to iterate over single values again, you only have to use:

```
for value in a:
    if value.weekday < 6:
        print(value)
```

However, it is much *faster* to use vectorised operations:

```
df['Date'][df['Date'].dt.weekday < 6]
```

That produces a series of weekday timestamps. If you wanted to select rows in the dataframe based on weekdays, apply the filter to the whole dataframe:

```
df[df['Date'].dt.weekday < 6]
```